# How are items enumerated in Japanese restaurant menus?

Tags: translation, food

I've been asked to render a restaurant menu in Japanese, even though I'm not very good with the language (don’t ask).  The original menu has ingredient lists for each entry, usually like this:

> Spam, bacon, sausage, eggs, ham.

But also like this:

> Spam, bacon, and eggs.

And sometimes like this:

> Spam on bread with sausages, bacon, and ham.

My question is, how are these lists normally presented in Japanese restaurant menus? Should I make them like the original with commas, i.e. this:

> スパム、ベーコン、ソーセージ、卵、ハム。

Or do they use a lot of とs like this?

> スパムとベーコンとソーセージと卵とハム。

Or something else?

And for the last example above, is it weird to do a direct rendering like this?:

> ブレッドにスパムとソーセージとベーコンとハム。

What's a natural/nonawkward way of expressing such enumerations?

Comment: Forget using particles; This is no prose.   Even in prose, we do not go 「AとBとCとD」.   See an actual example here:  http://www.dennys.jp/safety/raw-material/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ordinary, ingredient list looks like:

```
スパム、ベーコン、ソーセージ、卵、ハム
```

No 。is used, because the list is not a sentence.

For

```
Spam on bread with sausages, bacon, and ham.
```

It should look like:

```
スパムの乗ったパン、ソーセージ、ベーコン、ハム
```

Also I suggest to use ランチョンミート for spam, because スパム is not common for Japanese. So last example should be:

```
ランチョンミートの乗ったパン、ソーセージ、ベーコン、ハム
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

"Spam" was not a real item, just an example. It's a joke from this Monty Python comedy sketch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M_eYSuPKP3Y
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_%28Monty_Python%29